# views on top of other views

Tags: views, panels

I have a content type called News. There are three taxonomy terms for this content type (In the News, Success Stories, Events)

I want a page that shows each taxonomy term, with the newest three nodes summary, respective of that term, underneath it.

For Instance:

**IN THE NEWS:**

january 5th, 2001
blah blah blah blah blah

february 5th, 2002
blah blah blah blah blah

**SUCCESS STORIES:**

March 1, 2011
blah blah blah

Jan 2, 2012
date blah blah blah

**EVENTS:**

march 1, 2010
blah blahb lah

may 3, 2011
blah blah blah

Is there a way to do this using Views alone or should I make a separate view for each section and use Panels to show the three views?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Views attachment to put them all together.  See example at http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments

Comment: This seems to be a perfect case for using views attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need separate views. I suggest using the same view with different displays (that differ only in the filter).

The natural solution would be to set the term field as the grouping field in the Style settings. But this does not work for you, because it does not allow you to specify how many items to display in each group. If you are unlucky, all recent nodes belong to a single term, so no nodes for the other terms would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can put other views in the header and footer area of a view. This means you could create three views (one for each type) and in the `Success stories` place the `in the news` in the header and `events` in the footer.

I haven't checked out the Drupal 6 version of views-3 but think that the same is possible.